# Casting between different UnsafePointer<T> in swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I am trying to use a C-Api from swift. As an example the C-Api goes this ways:

```
void doThingsOnRawData(const unsigned char* data);
```

Swift converts this to:

```
void doThingsOnRawData(UnsafePointer<UInt8>);
```

Now I want to pass the data from an NSData to the function. NSData.byte returns the type:

```
UnsafePointer<()>
```

1. Is this some kind of void* type?
2. At least swift won't accept it as an `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`. What do I do to cast this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`struct UnsafePointer<T>` has a constructor

```
/// Convert from a UnsafePointer of a different type.
///
/// This is a fundamentally unsafe conversion.
init<U>(_ from: UnsafePointer<U>)
```

which you can use here

```
doThingsOnRawData(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes))
```

You can even omit the generic type because it is inferred from the context:

```
doThingsOnRawData(UnsafePointer(data.bytes))
```

**Update for Swift 3:** As of Xcode 8 beta 6, you cannot convert
directly between different unsafe pointers anymore.

For `data: NSData`, `data.bytes` is a `UnsafeRawPointer` which can
be converted to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` with `assumingMemoryBound`:

```
doThingsOnRawData(data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))
```

For `data: Data` it is even simpler:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { doThingsOnRawData($0) }
```

Comment: Does this copy the data?

Comment: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes) doesn't work for me. Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)'.

Comment: @ Martin R: Version 7.2.1

Comment: @MartinR thanks, do post if you find any other alternative.

Comment: @Jerzo: I cannot reproduce the problem with Xcode 7.3.1. For `data` of type `NSData`, `let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)` compiles without problems.

Comment: Just in case other Swift3 people come here, I needed w/ 08-07 snapshot `UnsafePointer(OpaquePointer(other))`

Comment: @Logan: What type has `other` in your case?

Comment: `UnsafePointer<T>`, where `T` can be anything, so let's say `other = UnsafePointer<T>`, it would be more explicitly: `UnsafePointer<SomethingElse>(OpaquePointer(other))`

Comment: @Logan: You are right, the above code does not compile anymore with the latest snapshot. In this particular case, `data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)` would be an alternative. I'll update the answer later, when I have more time. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MartinR I like the solution you proposed there, I think it reads a bit more nicely, thanks!