# In Xcode 8 (Swift 3) what does UnsafeMutablePointer<_> mean?

Tags: xcode, swift3, unsafe-pointers

The following code:

```
  var mutableDataP = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>(audioBuffer.mData)
  let stereoSampleArray = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(
      start: mutableDataP,
      count: nBytesInBuffer/sizeof(Int16)    // Int16 audio samples
  )
```

gives the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to expected
>   argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>'

What is an UnsafeMutablePointer<__> and how do I cast to it? I tried all the casting variations I could think of and got un-understandable diagnostics for each and I've run out of ideas. I find the documentation on the various UnsafeMutablePointer types unhelpful, and no mention at all of '<_>'.

Comment: The double underscore in UnsafeMutablePointer<__> is actually a single underscore. I entered double because a single underscore vanishes in StackExchange.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359735/casting-between-different-unsafepointert-in-swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
let stereoSampleArray = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &audioBuffer.mData){
       return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(
              start: $0,
              count: nBytesInBuffer/MemoryLayout<Int16>.size    // Int16 audio samples
             )
       }
```

Where `audioBuffer.mData` is a `var`

Comment: Putting '&' in front of audioBuffer gives "ambiguous use of init". And 'MemoryLayout' is an unresolved identifier.

Comment: Probably the 2nd problem (unresolved identifier) is because I didn't convert the project to Swift 3 yet. I'm trying to get it to build successfully so I can use the convert tool. So I just need to find out how to write the expression for mutableDataP.

Comment: I see, check the edited answer. replace `MemoryLayout` if you're still in swift2.