# Access object created in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, interop

We have an Objective C library that creates objects that are meant to be used in Swift code.

The function returns the object as an id. This is the declaration in Objective C header file (Clazz.h). The header file has been exposed in bridging header as required for interoperability.

```
+ (id)getObject;
```

The pointer returned is an instance of AVAssetWriter*. To access this API in Swift, I followed the steps in below post: 
[Objective-C pointer and swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288819/objective-c-pointer-and-swift)

This is the Swift 3 code consumer code:

```
let obj = (Clazz.getObject() as! UnsafeMutableRawPointer).assumingMemoryBoundTo(to: AVAssetWriter.self).pointee
```

It built fine. However, when this code executes, the app seems to crash.

In Clazz.h, I declared the function as:

```
+ (AVAssetWriter*)getObject();
```

and tried to use it in Swift as,

```
let obj = Clazz.getObject() as AVAssetWriter
```

Code built fine but it failed when it was executed.

How do we access Objective C created objects in Swift?

Please note that I was able to inspect the value in swift code and the problem is not in bridging. Also, the memory location is not dangling.

Comment: The obvious answer is to rewrite the Objective C declaration so that it returns the actual type rather than `id`. You say that `as AVAssetWriter` failed at runtime. What happened?  How did it fail?

Comment: sorry... it did not fail there. The typecast worked but on inspecting it, it shows a long value and ObjectiveC.NSObject & not AVAssetWriter. It failed when I tried to use it as AVAssetWriter and accessed one of it's properties.

Comment: So what was *that* error when you attempted to access the property?

Comment: I found the issue... as a java developer, I was so used to declaring the type with the variable name that I forgot to mention obj as of type AVAssetWriter. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure. Perhaps ask another question showing your code and the exact message from the compiler

Comment: yes... will do. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By declaring obj variable as below, things worked

```
let obj:AVAssetWriter = Clazz.getObject() as AVAssetWriter
```